# Как разделить один большой код на несколько для удобства?

Tags: python

У меня уже достаточно огромный код, уже неудобно писать. А можно его разделить на несколько файлов без когов? А то у меня там проблемы с ним, пытался.
Может разделить его и в каждом файле сделать client.run('')? Или большая нагрузка будет?

Comment: Что это за "коги"? А так - разделите на модули и подключайте их через import. Не вижу смысла `client.run('')`в каждом писать.

Comment: коги - cogs. Ну попробую... Надеюсь сработает

Comment: не встречал в python такой термин

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html, не это что-ли?

Comment: А, это что-то для ботов. Вообще с ними не работал. А в вопросе о них ни слова:-)